# What is the timestamp in the CameraX.ImageInfo?

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camerax

I want to get the CameraX(analyzer) frame created timestamp, but when I use `imageProxy.getImageInfo().getTimestamp()` I get a timestamp that is shorter than `System.currentTimeMillis()`, so I think they are not same timestamp style.

how can I transfer it to normal timestamp like the stamp of `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

> thanks @LexFerrinson, the `imageProxy.getImageInfo().getTimestamp()` is here https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageInfo#getTimestamp() but I dont know how to transfer it to currentTimeMillis.

for example:

```
2022-06-13 15:33:52.539 ... D/l:  System.currentTimeMillis():1,655,102,032,539
2022-06-13 15:33:52.578 ... D/l:  imageProxy.getImageInfo().getTimestamp():17,268,452,439,387
```

> I got the timestamp form camerax analyzer

cameraX version:

```
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.1.0-alpha09"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.1.0-alpha09"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha29"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:1.1.0-alpha29"
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageInfo#getTimestamp()) says, timestamps depend on the source providing the images.

If you are using Camera2 (I'm not sure if CameraX can use Camera1), you have to check [`SENSOR_INFO_TIMESTAMP_SOURCE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#SENSOR_INFO_TIMESTAMP_SOURCE) of the camera you are using:

- If it returns `UNKNOWN`, you can basically assume nothing about the timestamps except that they are monotonically increasing, so you can only compare them with the timestamps provided by the same camera
- If it returns `REALTIME`, then the timestamps will have the same base as `SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()`

So, you can't really use any of them to get `System.currentTimeMillis()` since it is a wall-clock which is not guaranteed to be monotonic.

Answer (score 1):

Eyjafl links to the documentation, but I'd like to add that for UNKNOWN, there are some basic guarantees:

> However, the timestamps are roughly in the same timebase as `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()`. The accuracy is sufficient for tasks like A/V synchronization for video recording, at least, and the timestamps can be directly used together with timestamps from the audio subsystem for that task.

even though there isn't the same guarantee of precision as with `REALTIME`.

Answer (score 0):

according to official documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageInfo#getTimestamp() image timestamp is a long, which means that as every timestamp, it returns the number of milliseconds from January 1st 1970.

Comment: what about `System.currentTimeMillis()`?

Comment: I saw the document before your answer but I cant understand it.

Comment: @normidar if you get the currentTImeMillis() and you convert it to date format with `Timestamp ts=new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());  
                Date date=new Date(ts.getTime());  
                System.out.println(date);` you should see the current time of the system. Now if you do the same with the timestamp of the picture you should see when it was taken.

Comment: did you do it ? they are different timestamp.

Comment: @normidar should they have same timestamp? Is the picture created in your program or is it a stored picture that you get from elsewhere? Could you give me both timestamp longs?

Comment: @normidar yeah, when I take a picture from android camera I save it with its timestamp and it is a correct long.

Comment: yes, I logging its , the System.currentTimeMillis() is `1655101458374`  the `ImageInfo().getTimestamp()` is `16694240914582`  get Timestamp is 10x+ bigger than `currentTimeMillis()`

Comment: The first number corresponds to Monday January 13 2022 06:24:18 UTC. The second number corresponds to Wed Jan 07 2499 xd. Are you doing any kind of previous operation with that number? Have you tried other pictures?

Comment: no, I get the number form `ImageProxy image` arg in the `ImageAnalysis.Analyzer`.     @LexFerrinson